# Passing meta elements through callback function in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

When I pass elements through callback function like in this example found on the official `scrapy documentation.`

I was wondering if the element `item` passed to `parse_page2`once modified inside the aforementioned function could be retrieved modified in the `parge_page1` function.

I mean assume the example below. In the `parse_page2` function we add the `response.url` into the 'other_url' field.

Does it exist a way to get 'other_url' inside `parse_page1`after the execution of `parse_page2` has completed?

```
def parse_page1(self, response):
    item = MyItem()
    item['main_url'] = response.url
    request = scrapy.Request("http://www.example.com/some_page.html",
                             callback=self.parse_page2)
    request.meta['item'] = item
    return request

def parse_page2(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['other_url'] = response.url
    return item
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating your item in the parse_page1 function, you can simply pass the response.url in the meta dict, and create the item in your parse_page2 function.

```
def parse_page1(self, response):
    return Request(url="http://www.example.com/some_page.html",
                   meta={'main_url':reponse.url},
                   callback=self.parse_page2)

def parse_page2(self, response):
    item = MyItem()
    item['main_url'] = response.meta['main_url']
    item['other_url'] = response.url
    return item
```

Or, if you really want to return the info from the parse_page2, you can callback parse_page1, and add a conditional in your function:

```
def parse_page1(self, response):
    if "other_url" in response.meta:
        do something
    else:
        do something else
```