# scrapy save different yield dic in same json object

Tags: json, python-3.x, scrapy

the codes I have on scrapy are shown below:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for quote in response.css('div.search-item '):
        f = quote.css('a.stack::attr(href)').extract_first()
        f = response.urljoin(f)
        # print(f)
        yield {
            'text': quote.css('span.tags::text').extract_first(),
            'title': quote.css('h3 em::text').extract_first(),

            }
        yield response.follow(f, self.parse_program)

def parse_program(self, response):
    def extract_with_css(query):
        return response.css(query).extract_first().strip()

    yield {
         'name': extract_with_css('div.headline h1::text'),}
```

The result turn out to be like:

```
 {'text':"sdada",'title':"12321q"}
 {'name':"sdasdsa"}
```

I want to make it like:

```
{'text':"sdada",'title':"12321q",'name':"sdasdsa"}
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use request meta for this, and yield the item only when you have all the data

```
def parse(self, response):
    for quote in response.css('div.search-item '):
        f = quote.css('a.stack::attr(href)').extract_first()
        f = response.urljoin(f)
        # print(f)
        data = {
            'text': quote.css('span.tags::text').extract_first(),
            'title': quote.css('h3 em::text').extract_first(),

            }
        yield response.follow(f, self.parse_program, meta={"data": data})

def parse_program(self, response):
    def extract_with_css(query):
        return response.css(query).extract_first().strip()
    data = response.meta["data"]
    data['name'] = extract_with_css('div.headline h1::text')
    yield data
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest this.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651723/passing-meta-elements-through-callback-function-in-scrapy